# how to put one div in front of a other in html?

Tags: html

i have a problem, I have two div:

1. is a image and also its written first in the html code
2. is some text, written after the first div

now I have the problem: I see the first div over the second div this means I dont see the text.
I thought that if I write the second after the first I will se the second over the first.

is this normal? any solution?

Comment: Post your html and css

Comment: Perhaps `z-index` will help you. There is not enough information to say it for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you looking..?

```
  <html>
    <body>
      <style>

       #div_1
       {
         position:absolute;
         left:0px;
         top:0px;
         z-index:-1;
       }
     </style>

    <div id='div_1'>
       <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png" > 
    </div>

    <div style="color:#0000FF"  id='div_2'>
       <p>This is some text.</p> 
    </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try investigate the css property [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: This should have been a commentt

Comment: And that too will probably wont work, better to check for the "position" property.